# Locus of a sphere tangential contact through two given points touching a given plane

Tags: geometry

A set spheres passing through two points $(xP,yP,zP),(xQ,yQ,zQ),$ not in XY plane, are tangent to the XY plane.

Find the locus of point of tangency in XY plane.

EDIT 1:

Find the locus when $ xP=0, yP=0. $

Comment: You mean the locus of all spheres that pass through these two points as well as have the $XY$ plane as a tangential surface?

Comment: No. Required is the tangentcy point when sphere changes size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $C=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ be the center of a sphere passing through points $P$, $Q$ and tangent to the XY plane. The radius of such a sphere is $z_0$ and the conditions $CP=z_0$ and $CQ=z_0$ can be written as
$$
\begin{align}
&(x_P-x_0)^2+(y_P-y_0)^2+(z_P-z_0)^2=z_0^2,\\
&(x_Q-x_0)^2+(y_Q-y_0)^2+(z_Q-z_0)^2=z_0^2.\\
\end{align}
$$
The points of tangency have coordinates $(x_0,y_0)$ in the XY plane. We obtain the equation of the locus they form by eliminating $z_0$ from the equations above. After some straightforward algebra one gets:
$$
(z_Q-z_P)x_0^2+(z_Q-z_P)y_0^2-2(z_Qx_P-z_Px_Q)x_0
-2(z_Qy_P-z_Py_Q)y_0+
z_Q(x_P^2+y_P^2+z_P^2)-z_P(x_Q^2+y_Q^2+z_Q^2)=0,
$$
which is the equation of a circle if $z_Q\ne z_P$, while it is a line if $z_Q= z_P$.

Comment: Thanks. May I also ask about the symmetrical special case?

Comment: I don't see any special feature in that case: just plug in $x_P=y_P=0$.